# Getting and processing a json from a service with tomcat 10 and process with Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, web, tomcat, service

I have configured the web.xml to have a servlet that answers me with the information that I want(JSON or HML). The problem is that I want to manage the response with java script and I do not know how to get the response with my js code placed in /SI.

My index and JS are in /SI
and when I summit the form I move to /SI/standar-Servlet.

I could place some js there to manage this response But I am not sure that is the answer. I need som js code that receives tha json response and process it.

I think I need to modify the form so that I call the serlvet but I wait for the result.

Thank you in advance.

This is my js form :

```
            var form = document.createElement("form");
            form.setAttribute("method", "post");
            form.setAttribute("action", "standar-Servlet");
```

This is my java in tomcat(I get correctly the response)

```
    protected void response(HttpServletResponse resp,String request,String valuesMsg)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out=resp.getWriter();

/*        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>");
        out.println("</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("standar-Servlet request: "+request);
        out.println("standar-Servlet response : "+valuesMsg);
       /* out.println("<p>");
        out.println("name fields: "+namesMsg);
        out.println("</p>");
        out.println("<p>");
        out.println("name fields: "+valuesMsg);
        out.println("</p>");*/
 /*       out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");*/
        resp.setContentType("application/json");
        resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        out.print(valuesMsg);
    }
```

this is my web.xml:

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>standarServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>SERVER.SERVLETS.standarServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>standarServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/standar-Servlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process the response of the request, you should use the fetch API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) instead of creating a `form` element:

```
async function makeRequest() {
  const response = await fetch('/standar-Servlet', { method: 'post' })
  const result = await response.json()
  console.log(result) // do something with result
}
```

Comment: I have tried but the the error object prommised in the network tab. And it still changes to standar-servlet .I will continue trying.